# I can't assign to a variable named 'CallTypeList'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

An unusual issue turned up in my VB.NET project. I was getting the "Object or With Value Not Set Exception" on a line of the form:

```
Dim CallTypeList as List(Of Object) = MyORM.RecordSetToDynamic(sql)
```

The right hand side of this is unimportant, but in general reads database records via a 3rd party API, and copies the fields into Dynamic ExpandoObjects, which are then individually boxed into the List(Of Object) - it works, don't worry about it.

I've spend 2 hours looking at all of the functional structures, but when I duplicated the line, moved it earlier in my function and called it xCallTypeList, the renamed one worked.

I thought that something else (Active X probably) was making the execution state uncertain, and continued debugging.

It was only when I exchanged the xCallTypeList and CallTypeList variable names that I discovered that I can't assign to the variable called 'CallTypeList'.

Does anybody know what's going on? My web searches suggest that there isn't anything peculiar with that variable name.

I should note that I'm currently using VS2013 Community, but I have recently installed VS2015 Professional, but I've yet to start using it (not sure if that makes a difference).

Thanks.

Comment: To add that assignment of the form 'Dim CallTypeList As List(Of Object) = New List(Of Object) From {"A", "B", "C"}' completely works in my project, so I might have to put it down to general unusualness and leave it at that,

Comment: Hi roryap - it's not clear what's null anyway. If I pop the RHS of the assignment into the watch window it returns a value. If I change the name of the variable, the assignment works, and apparently, if the RHS is of a simpler form, the assignment works.

Comment: " it works, don't worry about it." - it is the right hand side you should be worrying about if that is the exception you are getting. The left hand side cannot generate that error (on that line). Moving it to another point in your code probably meant it now was not returning nothing. Also you should switch option strict on

Comment: If you do a search through your code, do you see `CallTypeList` anywhere else in your code? Is it possible you have used the same variable name elsewhere in your code that could be interfering?